# Same height settings change for Card inside other parent element

Tags: html, css

The card under the "Latest Blog Post" heading in the aside section keeps its height. But, even though the settings are set to the same in the .inner-container cards, their heights move depending on the height of the view port. Why is it doing that when their settings are also set the same as the card in the aside section? For example if you drag the display area windows height up and down the the text under the images for the 3 cards moves. Thank you.

CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/centem/pen/EeaMEz

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alex+Brush&family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
 }
 
html {
    height: 100vh;
}
body {
    min-height: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li, a {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #edf0f1;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
    grid-template-rows: 10% 80% 10%;
    grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header"
    "sidebar main main main"
    "footer footer footer footer";
}

.header {
    grid-area: header;
    padding: 5px;
    color: cornflowerblue;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 30px 10%;
    background-color: #242524;
}

.logo {
    font-family: 'Alex Brush', cursive;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.nav_links {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav_links li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav_links li a {
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.nav_links li a:hover {
    color: cornflowerblue;
}

.sidebar {
    grid-area: sidebar;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.main {
    grid-area: main;
    padding: 5px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    background-color: #242524;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
}
.footer ul li {
    display: inline;
}
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .card-text {
      padding: 2px;
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      line-height: .5em;
  }

  .card-text a {
      color: crimson;
      font-size: 1.2em;
  }

  .card-image {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
  }

.inner-container {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.inner-container div {
    margin: 5px;
}

.inner-container .card{
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.inner-container .card-text {
    padding: 2px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    line-height: .5em;
}

.inner-container .card-text a {
    color: crimson;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.inner-container .card-image {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: *"For example if you drag the display area windows height up and down the the text under the images for the 3 cards moves."* This event does not occur to me when I try it on mobile settings. (I assume that's what you meant). However, the responsiveness overall is quite a mess. I would suggest looking into responsive frameworks such as Bootstrap or fiddle around with Flexbox more until you get your desired layouts. Right now there's way too many issues to focus on a specific problem at hand, because it's mainly a chain reaction of your overall responsive programming.

Comment: Therefore, it'd simply be too much work for other people to *"fix"* since there are so many issues.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons:
Default height of your images are not same and you didn't specified their height, I set the height to 100% see how it looks now:

```
  .card-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
 }
```

[codepen link](https://cdpn.io/shiponcs/debug/qBbmqbE/bZrQWEVymaxk)